# apt-get authentication error in OpenVZ Debian container

Tags: debian, apt, openvz

Whenever I receive upgraded packages from security.debian.org, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2.2-common ...
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? 
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

I'm running Debian 6 in an OpenVZ container. I have the following line in my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://security.debian.org squeeze updates/main updates/contrib
```

I have debian-archive-keyring installed and up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources.list template coming with OpenVZ is misconfigured. Run the following to correct it:

```
sed -i 's#security.debian.org squeeze updates/main updates/contrib#security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main non-free contrib#' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
```